# android app debugging

Tags: android

I have an app in android using camera with opencv which runs for about 1 minute and then turns off without returning any errors. It looks to me like some memory leak or something like that. How can I find out what is going on ?

Comment: Logs[.](http://vyou.com/rgasm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out the debugger. It's your friend, learn how to use it and you will save your sanity!

http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger01/lesson01.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html). Simple but powerful.